# Get "Selected variable has too many values." when using Orange Data Mining's Pivot Table widget (implying too many column values?)

Tags: orange

I am assuming there are too many columns in the (generated) pivot table when I get the "Selected variable has too many values." when using Pivot Table widget

Is there a way to increase?  If not which module can I edit in my local copy of Orange?